change dimensions of imported model in react-three-fiber / drei
I am making a custom configurator using react-three-fiber for my webapp. I'm taking in input dimensions from the user and need to alter my imported model size based on the data entered by the user.
suppose I have a model of a cardboard box but I need to change its size based on the user input data.
how can I do it???
Below is the link to the configurator I'm using as reference.(I am recreating it)
Original Configurator website
I have tried just basic scaling but cannot figure out how to change the specific dimensions
and also how will it affect the simulation.
